# Defining Foreign keys in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting an intermittent error

> An error while saving entities that do not expose foreign key property for their relationships

I believe it may be because I have not properly defined my relationships in my entity framework database layer.

I have defined a table with a 1:1 relationship as such:

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public FinalisedServices Service { get; set; }
```

Where SpproFinalisedServices is a foreign key. Should I have written it like so:

```
     public int FinalisedSerivce_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FinalisedSerivce_Id")]
    public FinalisedServices Service { get; set; }
```

or alternatively will adding virtual suffice:

```
    public virtual FinalisedServices Service { get; set; }
```

I originally assumed that entity framework would have handled the database foreign keys in the background.

Comment: Have you looked at the inner exception? That (usually) shows exactly which entity and relationship EF is having an issue with. And that should help diagnose the problem.

Comment: the problem is only occurring on the live system. I need to logo the inner exception as well, but was hoping to solve it before it happens again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public virtual ICollection<FinalisedQuoteStaff> JobManagers { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<FinalisedQuoteStaff> AllocatedStaff { get; set; }
```

This does NOT define a one to one relationship. Any time you include a collection, you are defining a one-to-many or many-to-many. Based on your other code, I assume you are going for a one-to-many. I.e. multiple managers and staff on one service. Please check this [tutorial](http://tutorial). You do NOT need to define a foreign key explicitly on Finalized Service. That's for situations where there are multiple foreign keys and/or foreign keys named differently than the foreign key table.

You also DO NOT need `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` - it is convention over configuration - it will do it by default. You would need that if you named the Id field something weird. It's automatic when you name it "Id."

Comment: sorry I should not have included the many to many relationship. they are nothing to do with the question, but i guess the answer is they are not required and not my problem

Comment: You need to post your whole tables. Change names if something is proprietary, just make sure they are consistent - little things like "s" at the end and the way you name things matter here, as I am sure you know.

Comment: @michael: As an example  public FinalisedServices Service { get; set; }  - this needs to be "FinalizedService," not plural. Assuming you have ONE service. Otherwise it needs to be a services collection.